# BorderLayout Swing

Tags: java, swing, awt, jscrollpane

I m using A `BorderLayout`. In the north position I m having a panel called `panNorth`, where I'm adding some component (say for one click I'm adding one button in the next row (gridlayout)). In the main frame in the center part I will add something later.

So what is my problem now is, when ever I'm adding new controls in `panNorth` the size getting increased and occupy the `BorderLayout's` center place. So I added a `JScrollPane` in the north side and added the `panNorth` in Jscrollpane, but nothing different happened.  The same thing is happening again; the size of the `JScrollPane` is expanding to the original size of the `panNorth` so it displays all the components, the scrollbar is not use full now.

So please suggest to me how to make visible only 3 rows at a time.

Comment: you should choose accepted answers to questions that people have answered for you.  That will help people in the future see which answer solved your problem.  (Click the check-mark below the voting buttons.)

Comment: In his defense he has a lot of unanswered question and the rest might have only a single incorrect answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using:

```
jScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(panNorth.getWidth(), desiredHeight));
```

This should force the `JScrollPane` to keep its preferred size in the North pane.

Comment: @ Surendhar: I'm happy jjnguy helped you -- now please upvote jjnguy's answer (as I have done), or better upvote it **and** select it as the chosen answer.